# How to redirect www to non-www?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I am using URL re-writer module provided by http://urlrewriter.net/ site. Can anyone tell me how can I use their module to redirect www.example.com to example.com (301 redirect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to redirect `www.example.com`:

```
<if header="HTTP_HOST" match="www.example.com">
    <redirect url=".*" to="http://example.com$0" permanent="true" />
</if>
```

And if you want to redirect everything except `example.com` to `example.com`:

```
<unless header="HTTP_HOST" match="example.com">
    <redirect url=".*" to="http://example.com$0" permanent="true" />
</unless>
```

Comment: @Gumbo <if> condition is working for me. <unless> is not working. <if> has one little mistake "http://example.com/$0" it should be "http://example.com$0" else it will redirect you from "www.ex.com/dom/about.aspx" to "ex.com//dom/about.aspx" notice the double slashes. Rest its fine, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<redirect url="http://www.example.com/(.+)$" to="http://example.com/$1">
```

Comment: Isn't the url only the part after the domain?

Answer (score 1):

**duplicate content  redirect none www to www asp.net**

```
<if  header="HTTP_HOST" match="^domain.com" url="/default.aspx$">
     <redirect to="http://www.domain.com/" />
</if>

<if header="HTTP_HOST" match="^domain.com" url="~/(.+)$">
     <redirect to="http://www.domain.com/$1" />
</if>
```

I test this code and its right

Answer (score 0):

I've never used urlrewriter, but it looks like you'd use the following (or something similar:

```
<redirect url="^(.+)$" to="http://example.com/$1" permanent="true" />
```

on the www.example.com site.

Comment: It seems that your rule will redirect ANY request, also not domain which is specified. I mean if web site bindings are set to few domains, all of them will be redirected to one given

Comment: Ah, yes you're right.  I'm used to .htacces, where it only affects the given path and subpaths.